How can I file a bug in gnome magnifier , it freezzes with 'push' setting
The screen freezes using magnifier with the setting 'mag cursor pushes contents around'.
(Accessibility>zoom>magnifier cursor pushes contents around)
It happens after a reboot & after awhile. It happens in ubuntu 22.04 but also in Debian 11&12.
Switching back to proportional  with:
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.a11y.magnifier mouse-tracking proportional
releases the frozen screen.
You can then switch back to 'push' the screen will not freeze again this session.
Resource hungry programs have become slow compared to Debian10
Don't know if this has anything to doe with the bug.
Question:
How do I file a bug for the gnome magnifier?
Bugzilla does not take any new bugs.
gitlab.gnome.org/ is out of order and looks depricated

This question is similar to: How do I report a bug?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Ubuntu 22.04 LTS is a somewhat old system (five releases ago) so I'd normally confirm the bug is in the current version (24.10) then may also confirm on the development version; then also report upstream if it's there...   As you mention very old releases; there is little point reporting upstream UNTIL you've confirmed it exists in a current version (ie. Ubuntu 24.10; or in Debian that'll be Debian 13)
